# How to set the group a user belongs to in FreeRadius?

Tags: freeradius

I have just started using FreeRadius. In the users file, I have a line

```
testing Cleartext-Password := "password"
```

How do I configure the groupname this "testing" user belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure group in **clients.conf**

like

```
client 192.168.1.0/24 {

  *Write your secret or nastype here. *

}
```

Here 192.168.1.0/24 is set of IPs...

Comment: how about, i need to create group called Admin and the member testing ?